# unable to start apache on OS X el capitan

Tags: apache

when I do

```
sudo apachectl -S
```

I get

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 21 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf:
Mutex type /private/var/log/apache2/ is not valid
```

Said line in `httpd-mpm.conf` looks like this

```
Mutex file: "/private/var/log/apache2/" default
```

I am an Nginx guy and not familiar with Apache at all. How do I make it work?

Comment: Can you try to remove the space between "file:" and "/private/var/log/apache2/"?

Comment: @tiziano didn't help.. `Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:"/private/var/log/apache2/"`